# Scroll is not smooth for image listing web page

Tags: javascript, angular, image

I am trying to create an image listing website in angular like the google photos. I have a custom scrollbar which lists the month and year. When user moves the scroll thumb, the image list should scroll. 
I have written,

```
scrollContainer = document.getElementById("photosContainer");
scrollContainer.scrollTop += 20;
```

and the `mousemove event` will fire the above code. 
There are about 5000 `img` tags and for testing purpose the `src` is just an avatar icon hardcoded.
So no changes happen to the image when it is scrolled.

```
 onmousemove(){
  this.scrollThumbPosition = <value>;
}
```

This will move the scrollbar thumb. The scrollbar and everything works fine if there are upto a 1000 images.But when there are more than 1000 images,

1. Scroll thumb wont move when dragged.
2. The image list wont move.

But when the `mouseup` action is triggered the Ui responds.
Is there a way to smoothen the performance of the page with huge number of image tags?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a simple CSS solution? (Edit: added `will-change: scroll-position` thanks to lucifer63).

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  will-change: scroll-position;
}
```

[scroll-behavior: smooth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) politely asks the browser to smooth out automated scrolling (i.e. not user scrolling)

[will-change: scroll-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) lets the browser know where a performance hit is expected. It is only intended as a last resort if you are still seeing issues.

Edit:

Or if you want a pure JS approach, you can use the `window.scroll()` fuction:

```
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 20,
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

``

Comment: +i think this is that exact case in which "will-change: scroll-position;" is needed

Comment: @lucifer63 Thanks. Updated my answer. MDN suggests that this shouldn't be used eagerly, only as a last resort, so I have mentioned that caveat.